# Java logic issues

Tags: java, loops

I'm working on a method that finds the first instance of a given value and returns its position. It works for some cases, but if I give it an array of [1,2,3], and set the value to 2, it returns 0, instead of 1. I'm not sure why, either. Here is the code:

```
int b = 0;
for(int a = 0; a < values.length; a++) {
    if (values[a] == find){
        b++;
    }
}
return b-1;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because you are returning b-1.  In fact, if you need to find the same instance and return the index, you wont even need the variable b. You could achieve this with something like this:

```
for( int a = 0; a < values.length; a++) {

if (values[a] == find){
   return a;
 }
}

return -1 // Notfound
}
```

Add the `return -1` line for when a value is not found, to use as a sentinel value.

Comment: It won't compile, as the return statement is not in the right place, I assume. Says this method must return a type int.

Comment: You didn't specified any definition on what to do when the value is not found. Try this, return a sentinel value of -1 when the value is not found in the array. (edited in answer)

Comment: A sample [program](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/Searcing.htm) with the logic @Sednus has mentioned.

Comment: Excellent, yes that works, apologies for not defining the question well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
for( int a = 0; a<values.length; a++) {
    if (values[a] == find){
        return a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not return `a` itself instead of doing `b-1`;

Maybe you can add a `break` statement too to stop iterating as you just need the position of first instance

```
    int b=0,result;
    for( int a = 0; a<values.length; a++)
    {

    if (values[a] == find)
     {
       result=a;
       break;
     }
    }

 return result;
```